# Catalyst reuse app code with multiple sites

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have several sites that all have very similar functionality. They allow a user to register, login, enter credit card information, and other common functionalities. The only parts that will be different are the design (templates) and some backend administrative functionality (essentially the area once logged in will perform different tasks), and each site will need its own database connect information. Is there a way to reuse this code effectively so I don't have to copy and paste? Should I be pointing these websites to the same Catalyst app, and then somehow handle only the different aspects differently based on the domain name that called on the Catalyst app. Or is it better to just have separate Catalyst apps and copy the code, since once logged in the sites will be different. I'm wondering if anyone has ever done anything similar to this before and knows the best way to handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got some experience with this. We have a series of applications that share some common base code for the CRUD functionality.

You just configure your perl paths and TT paths in such a fashion that modules and templates in the app override any equivalent in the common repo, and app modules can inherit from the common modules if/as required, eg:

```
/var/common
           /root
           /lib
           /and-so-on
/var/myapp1
           /root
           /lib
           /and-so-on
/var/myapp2
           /root
           /lib
           /and-so-on
```

Your main program `MyApp2.pm` has something like:

```
use lib '/var/common/lib';
use lib '/var/myapp2/lib'; # use lib behaves like unshift
```

Your `View::TT` config has something like:

```
include_path => [ '/var/myapp2/root', '/var/common/root' ];
```

And your modules can do things like:

```
package MyApp2::Controller::Foo;

use base 'Common::Controller::Foo';
```

...if you want to use most of the Common Foo but override certain aspects.

With the `include_path` setting, you can share common template stuff, and override it in the same way:

```
[%- PROCESS bar.tt -%]
```

will output `/var/myapp2/root/bar.tt` if it exists, or fall back to `/var/common/root/bar.tt` if it doesn't.

We've found this to be very elegant, effective and most of all, DRY.

---

**UPDATE**

An example to answer a question in the comment-trail about inheriting/overriding:

```
package MyApp2::Controller::Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Common::Controller::Foo';

sub baz :Local {
    my ($self, $c) = (shift, shift);
    # set something up that's peculiar to MyApp2's implementation of baz
    $c->stash->{bazconfig} = { ... };
    # ...
    $self->SUPER::baz($c,@_);
    # do something else peculiar
    # ...
}

sub quux :Local {
    my ($self, $c) = (shift, shift);
    # completely override the Common quux action
    # etc
    # ...
}

1;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the great answer. This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for. I just have one clarifying question. When you have `package MyApp2::Controller::Foo;

use base 'Common::Controller::Foo';`

If I want to reuse a controller, I would have to create that in each app and then have the `use base 'Common::Controller::Foo';` line? And also, if I provide actions in those controllers with the same name, then those will override the ones in the common package?

Comment: yes, that's pretty much how it works. You can override or extend actions from the common module. I've updated my answer with an example. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: Great! Thanks for being so helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, one last question. If I don't define a controller or action at all in an app that is using Common, then it will just look in common, is that correct?

Comment: If you don't define `MyApp2::Controller::Foo` at all, then Catalyst is not going to know to include `Common::Controller::Foo` in the list of supported paths/actions. It's only going to look in `/var/myapp2/lib/MyApp/Controller/` for controllers, after all. Any *actions* you don't define in the local version will be inherited directly from the common version, of course.

Comment: Right, sorry. Is there a good way to handle the different apps having different database connection information? Because if I am sharing CRUD functionality, and it gets passed to Common, if I use `$c->model('DB')` will that still be using app2's database connection information and not Common's?

Comment: As long as you've configured `$c->model()` in `MyApp2.pm`, that's what will get used. I would be wary of having the `MyApp2.pm` main program inherit from the `Common.pm` equivalent. In fact there shouldn't even *be* a `Common.pm` main program. (Using the term 'main program' in the Catalyst sense.)